# How to get an Canon 5400 printer working?

Tags: printing, helpfile

Can anybody help me to install a Canon printer MG5450 but coming up with 5400.
Then when you send to print it tries to print than nothing. Also how do you install drivers.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Canon USA website, there is no print driver available for that printer.

http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg5420#DriversAndSoftware